# jQuery slideToggle - adding changing icon after title

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'd like to change some of my text whenever slideToggle is activated.

I have a text when the toggle is closed and I want to add a + (plus) sign at the end of it. I want that sign to change to a - (minus) when the toggle is open.

I've tried it with the following code, but I couldn't find a way to add the plus/minus signs since there is no css change when the toggle opens/closes.

jQuery:

```
$(window).load(function(){
$(".header").click(function () {
    $header = $(this);
    $content = $header.next();
    $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
        $header.text(function () {
            return $content.is(":visible") ? "TITLE" : "TITLE";
        });
    });
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header"><span>TITLE</span></div>
<div class="content"><p>Expanded text</p></div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    background-color: #dc0032;
    padding: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Your logic works, just change `TITLE` in either side of the ternary to the values you want to set...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use pseudo element and you will be able to control the content by toggling a class. You can also easily change it to an icon or image later.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".header").click(function() {
    $header = $(this);
    $content = $header.next();
    $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
      $header.toggleClass('close');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #dc0032;
  padding: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
}

.header:after {
  content:" -";
  font-size:20px;
}
.header.close:after {
  content:" +";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header"><span>TITLE</span></div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Expanded text</p>
</div>
```